# jQuery Dialogue Box Not Closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a javascript/jQuery cookie confirmation box on my site as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/x7rAk/1/

```
var checkCookies = document.cookie;
var cookieNotice = '<div id="continue_box" class="cookie_box"><p>This website uses cookies to improve the user experience. For more information on cookies please see this <a href="/cookies/index.php">link</a>. By clicking continue, you agree to the use of cookies.</p><p class="cookies_accept"><span class="cookie_button" id="continue"><img src="/images/tick.png"/><span> Continue</span></span></p></div>';

    $('body').ready(function() {
        $('body').prepend($(cookieNotice).fadeIn(2000));
    });

var continueButton = 'span#continue.cookie_button';
var closeButton = 'span#close.cookie_button';
var closeNotice = '<div id="close_box" class="cookie_box" style="display:none"><p>You have agreed to the use of cookies. This allows us to bring you a better service by remembering your preferences.</p><p class="cookies_accept"><span class="cookie_button" id="close"><img src="/images/cross.png"/><span> Close</span></span></p></div>';

$('#continue_box.cookie_box').ready(function() {
    $(continueButton).click(function() {
        $('#continue_box.cookie_box').fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $('body').prepend($(closeNotice).fadeIn(1000));
        });
    });
});

$(closeButton).click(function() {
    $('#close_box.cookie_box').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

This is missing images and fonts etc. but it works exactly the same as on my site.

If you run the code, you will see that the box doesn't disappear when you click close.

First of all, how do I fix it, and secondly why does mine not work (I like to know why so I don't have to waste your time again :) ).

Thank you,

Connor

P.S. On my site it checks whether you have a cookie called cookiesAgree before showing it so the code is normally more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
 $(document).on("click", closeButton, function() {
    $('#close_box.cookie_box').fadeOut(2000);
});
```

The content is being added dynamically, so you need to register the event handler.

Comment: Works perfectly thank you, I'm going to look up registering event handlers then